# append columns of a csv file to lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, csv, append

I have a dataset which is formated in a tab separated file. What i want to accomplish, is to *append some of the columns of that file, to different lists.*

The file i am reading is somewhat like this:

```
   temperature  station.id  latitude    longtitude  sea.distance    altitude

1               S7          0            4          0               75
2               S8          1            5          3               400
3               S8          1.5          2          4               80
```

Notice that the first column is the index value, with no header, while the second column `temperature` has no values.

Now i am using a `csv.reader(infile, delimiter="\t")` to read the file and `append` to create a  `columns` list. Which as proven, is utterly wrong.

```
columns = []

for column in csv.reader(infile, delimiter="\t"):
            columns.append(column)
```

I have searched a bit and i found several functions and ways that might (or might not)  do the trick, but i am not sure as to which one i should use.
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

**Edit**: Result should be like this i think:

`lat = [0,1,1.5]`

A list for `latitude` values

Code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Python

import csv

columns = []

with open("/path/to/file/file.txt") as infile:    

    for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter="\t"):
        columns.append(row[1])
        print columns
```

**Edit2**: `print row` gives this:

```
['', 'temperature', 'station.id', 'latitude', 'longtitude', 'sea.distance', 'altitude']
[]
['1', '', '', '', 'S7', '0', '', '4', '', '0', '', '75']
['2', '', '', '', 'S8', '1', '', '5', '', '3', '', '400']
['3', '', '', '', 'S8', '1.5', '', '2', '', '4', '', '80']
```

Comment: What should the `columns`-list look like after your done?

Comment: @msvalkon i updated my question to include an example

Comment: So you want to add `lat = [0,1,1.5]` to the `latitude`-column?

Comment: @msvalkon nope not at all. Is my question that bad? I want to create a list containing  the values of latitude column.

Comment: oh sorry about that, I was looking at the wrong column in your data :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
>>> with open("test.csv", "rb") as f:
...     latitudes = [x[5] for x in csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t") if x]
...     
... 
>>> latitudes
['0', '1', '1.5']
```

`csv.reader` iterates over the *rows* of your csv-file. The code grabs every sixth item (remember, indexing begins at 0) from each row *if* the row exists (or does not evaluate to `False`, e.g. empty list). It does so using a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). You could write that list comprehension as a regular for loop:

```
>>> for row in csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t"):
...    if row:
...        latitudes.append(row[5])
...
...
```

---

EDIT: Your example data seems to have a bunch of extra tabs. I've updated the answer to take this in account. You should fix your input file though, unless you want to run into more problems.

If you sanitize your input file, you could turn the data into a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html). This allows easy manipulation and access of the csv data. Here's an example:

```
>>> data = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv("/tmp/test.csv", sep="\t")
>>> print data
index  temperature station.id  latitude  longtitude  sea.distance   altitude

NaN            NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN            NaN       NaN
 1             NaN         S7       0.0           4              0        75
 2             NaN         S8       1.0           5              3       400
 3             NaN         S8       1.5           2              4        80

[4 rows x 6 columns]

>>> data['latitude']
index
NaN      NaN
 1       0.0
 2       1.0
 3       1.5
Name: latitude, dtype: float64
>>>
```

Comment: it gives the same error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @KapelNick is your example data actually the data you're working with or something you handcrafted for this question? Are you *absolutely* sure its tab delimited. Can you print the rows? `for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter="\t"): print row`

Comment: these are the actual  data. `print row` works just fine. Might be that there are more than one tabs in some cases?

Comment: Updated the answer, have a look.

Comment: well now it works but zero doesnt show up in the output, `['1','1.5']`

Comment: Remove the `latitudes = latitudes[1:]` part and try again.

Comment: Now it works like a charm. Can u please hash some explanations  to your code? Thanks for your time

Comment: Added some explanation,

Comment: Wait, why can't i simply change the number inside `[]` and do the same things for another column?

Answer (score 0):

```
columns = []
for row in csv.reader(infile, delimiter="\t"):
    columns.append(row[1])   # here row[1] is the second column
```

Comment: it gives an error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: i already posted the traceback error. Code is at the bottom of my question

Comment: print the row[1] in the for loop. what does that give you?

Comment: same as before `IndexError: list index out of range` Maybe it has  to do with `temperature` being empty?

Comment: its probably because your file format. print only row. and see the output.

Comment: yeah.. now you can get your desired list. can't you?